# Breaking Insecure Elliptic Curve Cryptography

Tags: rsa, elliptic-curves, discrete-logarithm, modular-arithmetic

If you knew the entire equation of an elliptic curve $$y^2 = x^3 + ax + b~( mod ~~m)$$ given $a, b$ and $m$ which are all more than 70 digits in length, as well as a point $P$ and the point $t P$, with different orders, would it be possible to calculate $t$? What would be the fastest way to do this?

(I'm aware that $tP$ and $P$ not sharing the same order makes this less secure but I'm wondering how exactly to exploit it).

Comment: sorry for inadvertently removing 70 in my edit. thanks @MORNING_WOOD for fixing it.

Comment: Do you know the two orders ? A general solution doesn't seem to apply, so maybe looking at the numbers..

Comment: It depends on many things.. If P has order 2 and $t=2$ then it is trivial. If $P$ has order $2p$ for a large prime $p$, and $t=2n$ for some random $1\leq n\leq p-1$, then it will be hard. You'll have to give some more information.

Comment: The order of P is 93556643250795678718734474880013829509196181230338248789325711173791286325820 and the ratio of orders from P to nP is 1:60.

Answer (score 6):

You mention your point has order 
$$93556643250795678718734474880013829509\\196181230338248789325711173791286325820$$
 which factorizes as

$$2^2\cdot 3\cdot 5\cdot 7\cdot137\cdot593\cdot 24337\cdot 25589\cdot3637793\cdot5733569\cdot106831998530025000830453\cdot1975901744727669147699767.$$

Without much computing power, we can apply the Pohlig-Hellman algorithm to obtain 
$$t\bmod4, t\bmod3,t\bmod5,\ldots,t\bmod5733569.$$

Using the Chinese Remainder Theorem, we can combine all these results to get

$$t\bmod\left(4\cdot3\cdot5\cdots5733569\right),$$
i.e.
$$t\bmod443208349730265573969192476820.$$

As @Ruggero remarks, the other primes are only about 80 bits. So with $\approx 40$ bits of computing power we could also break that discrete logarithm. It takes a little more effort than the others though, so if $t < 400\cdots 0$, then you may as well only do the easy ones.

Comment: Could I reduce the computation by knowing t < 400000000000000000000000000000?

Comment: Yes, then you immediately get $t$, by the above.

Comment: Would I simply compute up to mod 3637793?

Comment: Well 5733569 is also doable. But you'll want to apply the Pohlig-Hellman algorithm.

Comment: I ran Pohlig Hellman and then applied CRT, and I thought I got the right answer, but it doesn't work out. Is this the right implementation?

1) Found order of P, denoting this as n

2) Created list of Pi, Qi, and Xi such that for each prime divisor in the factorization of n:
Pi = n/divisor * P,
Qi = n/divisor * Q
Xi such that Pi*Xi = Qi (found using discrete log)

Comment: Up to that was my implementation of Pohlig Hellman. Next, to implement CRT:

3) Multiplied together each prime divisor in factorization of n to receive 443208349730265573969192476820 which I denoted as M

4) A list of Bi such that for each prime divisor:
Bi = M/prime_divisor

5) Created a list of Bi' such that for each prime divisor:
Bi' = modular inverse (Bi, prime_divisor)

6) Computed the summation of Xi*Bi*Bi', denoted this sum as A

7) and then concluded that t = (A % M)

Comment: btw i got t = 230759028534002045278455145320

Comment: Perhaps, but there could be a bug anywhere. Why dont you add all parameters to your question, so we can have a go?

Comment: @CurveEnthusiast There is a missing "0" at the end of the order.

Comment: @Ruggero Thanks. And I cleaned up the computing power argument, that was very poorly done.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** this allows one to find a factor of $t$; find out how.

As an example, consider the multiplicative group modulo a prime, with a generator $g$. If $g^t$ is a quadratic residue, what does that say about $t$?

Comment: If the ratio of orders is 1:60 that would mean 60 is a factor of t, correct?

Comment: Maybe; try to prove it and you will see. :)

Comment: I think it stands but even knowing it is a multiple of 60, finding n this way would still take too long, no?

Comment: Nobody said you can completely find $t$. ;) (You can't, or at least not just from the order of $g^t$, since different values of $t$ may yield the same order.)

Comment: I was able to discover that, factoring and finding the cofactor for the prime divisor 7, and multiplying that cofactor h by P and tP produces the same point hP. Applying multiplicative properties, would I be correct in assuming that, given the cofactor h composed of factors {a,b,c..}, some combination of a*b*c*... will yield t?